# ios/xcode: core data throwing error on NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am new to IOS and trying to do a tutorial on core data.  The following code compiles but then crashes.  The breakpoint shows the error below but I can't figure out what it means or how to fix it.  [Tutorial.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)  Here is the code..

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity =[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FailedBankInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
            NSError *error;
            self.failedBankInfos = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
            self.title = @"Failed Banks";
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
managedObjectContext = (NSmanagedObjectContext *) nil
```

Here is what the console shows.

```
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.084 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.086 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.086 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.086 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.086 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.086 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.086 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.086 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.087 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.087 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.087 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.087 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.087 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.087 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.087 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.087 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.087 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.088 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.093 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.094 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.094 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.094 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.094 coredata-wend[39693:1857624] Name: Test Bank
    2015-01-14 19:28:50.094 coredat

a-wend[39693:1857624] Zip: 12345
(lldb)
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error message (or it's at least not a complete error message). But if it's correct, it's nearly self explanatory: `managedObjectContext` is nil, meaning that no value has been assigned to it. When you try to look up the entity description, you're passing a nil value for the second argument.

Why it's nil isn't obvious from the code that you've posted, but most likely you never assigned any value to it in the first place. At some point you need to assign an `NSManagedObjectContext` to that property. Where you do that depends on the structure of your app, but a likely place is in whatever code created this view controller.

Comment: I'm not quite to the point where I can understand what you mean.  This project is derived from apple's generic master detail app.  The  Ray Wenderlich tut linked to above put the following in app delegate file:  at-property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;  it is synthesized in .m file with _managedObjectContext
The following is also in main view controller:  at-property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;  It is synthesized in .m file with managed ObjectContext no underscore.  Could that be an issue?

Comment: It sounds like both your app delegate and your view controller have a `managedObjectContext`. But declaring that they exist isn't enough, you have to give them values too. Most likely, somewhere in your app delegate you need to set the view controller's `managedObjectContext` to have the same value as the one in your app delegate.

Comment: This method is in app delegate...- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
   
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }
    
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
I don't see it get called however.